# SerpApi expand result from "sports_restults"

Tags: serpapi

I am trying to scrape all the results of a soccer championship to create a timeline of the standings (as opposed to last available standing). To recreate this I need each individual result.
I already tried several different methods so, even though I am asking about SerpApi today, if you have different solutions, I would also like to know about it.

Based on the documentation: https://serpapi.com/sports-results
to show the results I would only need to call for it, and extract the json from sports_results

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "q": "manchester united",
  "api_key": "secret_api_key"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
sports_results = results["sports_results"]
```

my problem is that it only shows 6 matches. I would need to expand the results by "clicking" in "see more"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMGSd.png)

Serpapihas a pagination parameter, but it only works for the search results, and not for the "sports_results" element.

Any sugestions

Suggestion on how to scrap all results from a championship

Comment: As of November 2023, SerpApi doesn't extract all Google sports results and have this feature in the roadmap: https://github.com/serpapi/public-roadmap/issues/360